# My cordova webview app is really slower than in the android browser on the same phone

Tags: android, performance, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I built an android app with ionicframework and cordova.

But when i try to run on my Samsung Galaxy S4 the app is really slower than the same code in the webbrowsers of my phone.

How can i expect to have the same perfs ?

I've tried :

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

this.appView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
this.appView.getSettings().setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

With the last 3.6 cordova version

How can i do to have the same performance as i can see on the phone browser (with meta app-capable for example) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's hard to tell as you haven't provided code or a sample.
If you're not using the latest **Android 4.4 KitKat**, chances are you're using a really old [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

> Older versions of Android devices (4.0-4.3) use Android’s default
>   browser, which has significantly less performance and standards
>   compliance than modern Chrome. Using Crosswalk gives you a specific
>   and more performant version of Chrome to use on all Android devices,
>   in order to reduce fluctuations and fragmentation among devices.

This [article](http://blog.appgyver.com/heartbeat/steroids/android-chromium/) goes deeper in the problem and it's worth reading.

If you want to achieve the same performances you have in your web browser you can replace your web runtime using [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).

**Crosswalk** can be [easily](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html) integrated with **Cordova**.

With ionic framework you can [simply](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli#crosswalk-for-android):

```
ionic browser add crosswalk
```

If you'd like to specify a different version of Crosswalk, run `ionic browser list` to see which browsers are available and what versions. Then run:

```
ionic browser add crosswalk@10.39.235.15
```

[Nick Raboy](http://blog.nraboy.com/) has written an [interesting article](http://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/use-crosswalk-ionic-framework-android-apps/) which will guide you through all the step you need to take to integrate **Crosswalk** with **Cordova** + **Ionic Framework**.

Very helpful is the video with explains everything in a simple way.

Crosswalk can also be used in [Shared Mode](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/shared_mode.html):

> "Shared mode" allows multiple Crosswalk applications to share one
>   Crosswalk runtime. If the runtime is not already installed in the
>   device, it will be downloaded either from the Google Play Store, or
>   from a download location specified by the developer. When using this
>   feature, the Crosswalk library is not included in the application's
>   package, making it significantly smaller.

Producing a significant smaller APK file size.

It is not yet integrated in ionic framework and There is no road map to include this [feature](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/288).

Comment: If you are using Ionic, Crosswalk is not natively bundled. http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/

Comment: Using Crosswalk helped the performance of my app massively. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may get an Ndk error after doing so. I did. See solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979965/after-updating-android-studio-to-version-1-3-0-i-am-getting-ndk-integration-is

Comment: It seems the link to the article is dead... :(

Answer (score 1):

On a 1+1 I get the same performance through crosstalk as through the native webview. Unfortunately both these options are not quite as responsive as when the same app is tested on a 'venerable' iPhone 5s. So just using crosstalk might not be enough, but you could get lucky :)