# After updating Android Studio to version 1.3.0 I am getting "NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin" Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, deprecated

I have updated my Android Studio to version **1.3.0** before 3 days.

Before that I can use NDK and now I am getting error like ,

> Error:(50, 0) Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.

I can not find file gradle.property at project level.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: [Issue 182011: Gradle Plugin 1.3.0: can't use NDK](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182011)

Comment: @ EthicsDev : read my fully descriptive answer.

Comment: Is this an error or just a warning?

Comment: @ Igor Ganapolsky : It is an Error..!!

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Here is how to solve this issue :

1. add `gradle.properties` file to root folder of your project
2. add `'android.useDeprecatedNdk=true'` to `gradle.properties` file

Here is my gradle.properties :

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

And add it to root of your project :

[image: location of gradle.properties]

And rebuild your project.
Thats it.

Comment: after adding it i am having following Error:exception during working with external system:

Comment: @Kishan Soni : Please post question with your gradle file.. There will be some error in your project..!!

Comment: Whenever i change gradle plugin to 1.2.3 all things works fine but if i change plugin version to 1.5.0 again error occurs. But i need to use 1.5.0 only but nothing works well.

Comment: @Kishan Soni : For version  1.2.3 above, You have to use 'Experimental plugin' for NDK..!!

Comment: You have any idea how to use or work with "Experimental Pugin" its quite difficult and i did not find any tutorial regarding it :(

Comment: @Kishan Soni : Check this out -> http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96638/discussion-between-kishan-soni-and-andigeeky).

Comment: Did yo solve the problem with "exception during working with external system?"

Comment: @ Rolf Beh : I think you should post question with details and refer that to me..Lets see if I can help..!!

Comment: WIll you be able to build native code using Android.mk with this option?

Comment: @Raulp: I never did native development. but I think now you should try experimental plugin.

Comment: I tried experimental plugin by downloading the git sample for native activity code but I am always facing this problem with experimental plugin  -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027664/nativeactivity-sample-error-unknown-host-jcenter-bintray-com-by-using-gradle

Comment: ＠AndiGeeky I am having the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023308/ndk-integration-is-deprecated-in-the-current-plugin?noredirect=1#comment61598002_37023308

Comment: @ShinonChan : Have to tried above solution ? and still getting error?

Comment: I added gradle properties and set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" and I get this error.
Gradle 'android' project refresh failed
  Error: exception during working with eternal system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023308/ndk-integration-is-deprecated-in-the-current-plugin

Comment: @ShinonChan : Lets discuss this on your question. so you can get more specified help.

Comment: Doesn't work any more with Gradle Version 6.0+ as this option is depreciated and has been removed

Answer (score 4):

It mostly happens when you migrate your project from eclipse to Android studio, Or when you simply import eclipse project in android studio.

One more issue while getting this error, Mostly you dont have the file which named "gradle.properties" you need to create/add  in the project first and then set

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Answer (score 2):

**Deprecated** NDK is no longer supported. To avoid that error **remove** ***android.useDeprecatedNdk=true*** and do not make any **white space** in the Project Directory. If errors come again
then edit the ***build.gradle(Module:app)*** and add those line like below:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/','src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to solve this issue :

Go to gradle.properties file to root folder of your project
Remove `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` from your `gradle.properties` file

Android has removed `android.useDeprecatedNdk` so it won't work anymore