# NDK Integration in Android Studio Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am using Android studio version 1.3.1 and try to integrate the NDK by going to local.proprties and writing ndk.dir= and I got this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':tesstwo:compileReleaseNdk'.

> Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.

Please help me to sole this issue.

Comment: Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/31979965/4018207

Comment: @Mamata I have just added this statement in gradle.properties but its giving no such property and showing the same error.

Comment: @ Corrupt : Did you do same same accepted answer .??

Comment: @Mamata Yes I have followed same procedure as given in the link.

Comment: @ Corrupt : Did you have NDK in Android SDK ? and path you have added in ndk.dir= is right ??

Comment: @Mamata Yes Its right Installed from the studio itself and it generated the path for the ndk

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this to your build.gradle :

```
android{
        sourceSets {
              main {
                  jni.srcDirs = []
              }
          }
       }
```

Comment: @Corrupt : Glad It Worked :)

Comment: after 10 days of searching it finally worked. Thanks you

Comment: @ Milad Metias : Welcome :)

Comment: Note: this is to be added under like this `android { sourceSets {} }` (under android section). - newbie :)

Comment: @MaulikGangani: Done! Thanks :)