# Android studio multidex And Ndk issue

Tags: android, android-multidex

I am using android studio for developing android app. I have one project which is having two modules as library and both the modules having few libraries common(.so file) due to this I am getting multi-dex issue. Below is the gradle message

```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':ftrScanApiAndroidHelperUsbHost:compileReleaseNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/intel/BackUp/Ndk/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I tried below solution for this issue but this didn't work for me

```
defaultConfig{
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

build.gradle file:

```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application' // apply plugin: 'android'
> 
> android {
> 
>     signingConfigs {
>         config {
>             keyAlias 'xxx'
>             keyPassword 'xxx'
>             storeFile file('/home/intel/Downloads/xxx.jks')
>             storePassword 'xxx'
>         }
>     }
>     compileSdkVersion 21
>     buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId 'com.xxxx.xxx.xxx'
>         minSdkVersion 14
>         targetSdkVersion 14
>         versionCode 3
>         versionName "1.2"
>         signingConfig signingConfigs.config
>         multiDexEnabled true
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>             signingConfig signingConfigs.config
>         }
>         debug {
>             signingConfig signingConfigs.config
>         }
>     }
>     productFlavors {
>     }
>     sourceSets {
>         main {
>             jni.srcDirs = []
>             assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
>         }
>     }
> 
> }
> 
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
>     compile project(':pulltorefresh')
>     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
>     compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
>     compile files('libs/possdk.jar')
>     compile project(':ftrScanApiAndroidHelperUsbHost')
>     compile project(':ftrWsqAndroidHelper') }
```

local.properties below:

> sdk.dir=/home/intel/Takencode/Android/Sdk
>
> ndk.dir=/home/intel/Takencode/Android/Ndk

Is there any other solution for the above error? Any suggestion

Comment: Did you try it out in android lollipop?

Comment: you mean to say Compile sdk version...lollipop? @FabinPaul

Comment: Did you run the app on lollipop device/emulator?

Comment: How can I run the app without compiling...I am getting this error at compilation time..BTW I am using Lollipop OS device

Comment: Did you compile com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1?

Comment: Not yet, let me try this too..

Comment: post your gradle code

Comment: did you try by removing miltiDexEnable line

Comment: Just try `clean` and `rebuild` it.

Comment: yes @VivekPatel removing multidexEnable didn't work for me

Comment: please see the updated gradle message above

Comment: I think this issue relative to ndk not multidex, could you show me `local.properties` content and `build.gradle` that you config for ndk ?

Comment: grade code updated above @johnrao07

Comment: local.properties updated @mdtuyen clear and rebuild didn't work :( Anoop M

Comment: you have been config ndk path but in gradle file i don't see the path for library file

Comment: Pls see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after googling a lot I rectify the issues.Things that goes wrong for above issue.

`Case 1`:In modules I'm having jni and jnilibs few files common(.so files) ...so I deleted the jni folder because it containing the same .so file...removing redundancy and conflict from the project.

`Case 2`:There may be the case where modules(Library) and main project's theme,icons are different(defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` file). In order to correct that look for manifest file...make the module and main project theme same..

In my case module having below Theme

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and main project having

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

so I change module theme same as project theme.

Also add below line to manifest tag

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Once added above line add below line to application tag

```
tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
```

Now it  working flawless.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add dependency of support library in your `gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

If you already have a custom application you have to change that instead of extending `Application` you have to extends that class with `MultiDexApplication` like this

```
MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

}
```

If you don't have any custom application class only need to add this in manifest inside **application tag**

```
<application
   android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">   
</application>
```

If you don't need the whole `play service` you can remove the dependency and add only those dependencies you needed like this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
```

then no need to make your application `MultiDex`

For ndk you can see this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344995/ndk-integration-in-android-studio-error)

Answer (score 0):

**You may give it a try!**

> ```
> sourceSets {
>     main {
>         jni.srcDirs = []
>         assets.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
>     }
> }
> ```