# Android OCR: Importing to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ocr

I am trying to import an android ocr project from Eclipse(juno) to Android Studio. However faces the following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':eyestwo:compileReleaseNdk'.
```

> Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.

I have tried searching for solution for this problem and found several solutions from this links:

1. [After updating Android Studio to version 1.3.0 I am getting "NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979965/after-updating-android-studio-to-version-1-3-0-i-am-getting-ndk-integration-is)
2. [NDK Integration in Android Studio Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344995/ndk-integration-in-android-studio-error)

However, both methods did not work for me as the 2nd method leads to the error:

"Gradle DSL method not found:'sourceSets()'"

The 1st method leads to the error as shown below when I try to run the application:
[image]

The source code I used is from here: https://github.com/TheWall89/AndrOCR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this guide and u'll get the correct result... I have done this before..

[Tess Two guide for android studio](https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle)

[My project source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4H2r_RN8aIablVrREFMTG15VTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, saw the tutorial before but instructions are not specific. Re-tried and using your source code as sample, now manage to make it work :) thanks a lot