# Android Studio Gradle error implementing NDK

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I'm  trying to implement NDK in Android Studio and I have some problem with implementation:
I'm using Android Studio 2.0 Preview 3b, this is gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "lala.lala"
            minSdkVersion = 16
            targetSdkVersion = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
}
```

And this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.3.0-alpha5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have problem with Gradle:
Error:Unable to load class'com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl'.

[image: Error]

I have tried to resolve this error but unsuccessfully.

**SOLUTION:**

I have solved this problem, this two lines are problematic:

```
minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
```

And I have change this lines to this two:

```
minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
```

And this problem was resolved but there is some additionial problem which I resolve by adding:             `multiDexEnabled = true`
in `defaultConfig`

Comment: Check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979965/after-updating-android-studio-to-version-1-3-0-i-am-getting-ndk-integration-is and also restart Android studio..!!

Comment: I have restart Android Studio few times and nothing.
What I need to see in this link, i think it is nothing useful for me

Comment: Filip, have you figured this out?