# NativeActivity Sample : Error Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com' by using gradle experimental plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

I tried building the nativeActivity code from the samples in Android Studio 1.5.1 but I am getting this error :

```
    Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
   Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync 
   Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle</a>
```

I didn't find this issue with the projects not using Experimental Plugin **`(com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0')`** as used by all the Native samples from the android git hub.

my Project:NativeActivity build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean build.gradle?

Comment: You can open this url https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle-experimental/0.4.0/view#files/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental ?

Answer (score 0):

f you're unable to open this path

> https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle-experimental/0.4.0/view#files/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental.

Using proxy try again.

- run a proxy like freegate
- the root path project in cmd type `gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580`

Comment: I am able to open this path .But the issue remains!

Comment: Try this 1. run a proxy like freegate  2.the root path project in cmd type `gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580`

Comment: can you please tell what are you trying to do by performing this command?