# NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-ndk, crosswalk

I am using Ionic and I never had this problem before I added Crosswalk Web View. I also don't have a problem when I use cordova android@4.1. This error is occuring with cordova android@5.1.1 with all versions of crosswalk.

- Android Studio v2.1
- Gradle Version v2.2.1
- Android Plugin Version v1.5.0

I am getting this error in Android Studio when I try to sync my gradle. I am using lastest revision of sdk-23 and ndk tools.

```
NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin
 Error:(186, 0) Consider trying new experimental plugin
 Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration
```

I added gradle properties and set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" and I get this error.

```
Gradle 'android' project refresh failed
  Error: exception during working with eternal system
```

Comment: Would you consider using Gradle version 2.13 and Android plugin version 2.1.0 ?

Comment: Sure if it works, how do I change that?

Comment: @ Shinon Chan : Have you rebuild your project ?

Comment: yes, i tried rebuild with ionic build android as well as rebuild project from android studio and sync project with gradle files, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Shinon Chan : Do one thing : File -> Invalidate cache & restart ..!!

Comment: still the same error....

Comment: @ShinonChan : Can you post screenshot of where you have added `gradle.properties` ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/agXPzoJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111087/discussion-between-andigeeky-and-shinon-chan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Android plugin version 2.1.0

In your build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0"
    }
}
```

You need to install gradle 2.13 on your machine. Android plugin 2.0.0 and upper does not work with gradle version below 2.9 included.

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip

You may have more changes to do according to your gradle build script implementation.

Comment: i'm upgraded Gradle version 2.13 and Android plugin version 2.1.0 but it's still giving me the "NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin", any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem on Android studio 3.2.1 with updating Gradle and Android plugins version to

> Gradle Vesion **4.6**
>
> Android plugin version **3.2.1**

[image]